# Compressing (Gzip or Deflate) Shows, Lists and views in Couchdb

Tags: performance, couchdb, gzip, deflate, http-compression

It seems that couchdb automatically compress all its _attachments when requested with the correct header. But unfortunately this doesn't happen for views, show or lists.

Is there any way to achieve a compression before returning the result to the client?

Is using a third party library like [deflatejs](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate) (didn't test it yet) a bad approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use js-deflate in show and list functions, but you cannot do it in view functions. I also suspect it would be inefficient (just a guess, test it if you want numbers).

Until CouchDB does not [support gzip encoding](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-448), the easiest solution is to put a reverse proxy in front of CouchDB to do the compression. For example you can use nginx with the [HttpGzipModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule).

Comment: great, thanks for the proxy idea, I believe that works best for now :)

Answer (score 1):

The Couchbase distribution of CouchDB (Couchbase Single Server) supports Google's snappy compression for the JSON files on disk.  I believe the same goes for the views, but I'll have to defer to someone better qualified.

Comment: As explained [on their blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/driving-performance-improvements-couchbase-single-server-20), the compression is for the contents written on disk, not for communication with the client.