# Compress Couchdb replication traffic

Tags: android, ios, couchdb

I need one way replication from server to CouchOne Mobile(both iOs and Android). I sniffered traffic and see there is simple text JSON without compression.
Is it possible to speed up replication process and encrypt traffic if possible?

Comment: Have you tried putting a proxy as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522595/compressing-gzip-or-deflate-shows-lists-and-views-in-couchdb/7527222#7527222)?

Comment: @MarcelloNuccio No. But i think this doesn't work cuz replication it's internal couch process and couch does'nt support compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcello Nuccio's suggestion of using a proxy is your best option at the moment as CouchDB does not support GZip compression natively. Because replication is done using the public HTTP api the proxy will work fine.

Lets assume your mobile app is running on `M` and you have a server `S`. Currently you will probably have the replication set up on `M` to pull from `S`. If you add a reverse proxy, `P` in front of `S` then you just need to change the replication so `M` pulls from `P`.